# Flutter: I want to get data from firebase realtime database, everytime the application loads

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I managed to get the data from the firebase real-time database, but I can't use it inside the app. Based on the data, I want to show different screens (Activities). For example: If the user paid then show the "Paid" screen, otherwise show the "Pay Now" screen. I couldn't use the variable used inside eg: `paid_status` , outside from the below scope. So, I declared it as a global variable in another file.

```
package_stream.listen((DatabaseEvent event) {
  globals.paid_status = event.snapshot.value;
});
```

With the above code, it works but every time, the user closes the app and login again, the variable value is changed or kept old (after the database is updated). I want to get the value from the database every time the user opens the app or logout and login again.

I used below code to get the data:

```
setState(() {
 
  DatabaseReference paid_stat = db_reference.child('Records/${uid}/Paid');
  // Get the Stream
  Stream<DatabaseEvent> package_stream = paid_stat.onValue;
  // Subscribe to the stream!
  package_stream.listen((DatabaseEvent event) {
    globals.paid_status = event.snapshot.value;
  });
});
```

Comment: If you need to get latest data on the realtime database, you could just use get() method. Check following https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/read-and-write#read-data-once

Comment: @BurakAkkaş For that it needs to have `async` function and then it comes to the same point that the variable declared inside can't be accessed outside (the reason I declared the global variable
`db_reference.child('Records/${uid}/Paid').get().then((snapshot) {
         global.paid_status = snapshot.snapshot.value;
         print(snapshot.snapshot.value);
      });`

Comment: Instead of using a global variable or setting state yourself, consider using a `StreamBuilder` for showing the value from the database. That handles all state management and changes in the value automatically for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself :

1. I created an `async` Future function using `get()` to return the `snapshot`.
2. Using the `snapshot.value`, I showed different screens/activities.